# vagrant shell provisioner stops being able to install docker

Tags: docker, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have been using the Vagrantfile below to create virtual machine and the same time install docker on the vms by simply running vagrant up.

Now this script fails whenever i make subsequent attempt to create virtual machine and install docker.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

# vi: set ft=ruby :

boxes = [
    {
        :name => "manager1",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.10",
        :mem => "512",
        :cpu => "1"
    },
    {
        :name => "manager2",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.11",
        :mem => "512",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "manager3",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.12",
        :mem => "512",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "worker1",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.13",
        :mem => "1024",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "worker2",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.14",
        :mem => "1024",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "worker3",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.15",
         :mem => "1024",
         :cpu => "2"
    }
 ]

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.vm.boot_timeout = 2000

  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v, override|
      override.vm.box = "base"
  end

  # Turn off shared folders
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: true

  boxes.each do |opts|
    config.vm.define opts[:name] do |config|
      config.vm.hostname = opts[:name]

      config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
        v.vmx["memsize"] = opts[:mem]
        v.vmx["numvcpus"] = opts[:cpu]
      end

      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", opts[:name]]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", opts[:mem]]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", opts[:cpu]]
      end

      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: opts[:eth1]
    end

   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        apt-get update
        apt-get -y upgrade
        apt-get -y install \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        software-properties-common
        curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
        add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
        apt-get update
        apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
        getent group docker || groupadd docker
        usermod -aG docker vagrant
        service docker restart
    SHELL
  end
end
```

I keep having this error

```
manager1: E
manager1: : 
manager1: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.6.8-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
manager1:    
manager1: Hashes of expected file:
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA512:6eb0014637ad22d560eba5178b5d5cc54cdcc9ed3b272aebee3985f96738f1e7d40ed69894619b151255683489c22fd9ea70b162ace56798e298d9a0d8da67e2
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA256:46f1029a59484e58f21ecc45ae58bbe90620e1616d73048aaa61169f9ef957af
manager1:     - SHA1:7a18fb24a5cd293cdd0f2f7e1c2ffd2703f2e035 [weak]
manager1:     - MD5Sum:85967f85ea77756f14fc57523a7c29d0 [weak]
manager1:     - Filesize:28140650 [weak]
manager1:    Hashes of received file:
manager1:     - SHA512:d9ba9dc20038dc0310d3d61bdc55fca7ce7123caf1f1f4dde8a06ea47ec917cb64a94d49b9cf5dd918058a1a41dc501a8953b8aa2a2401b2a00329b9cd0d1b99
manager1:     - SHA256:689afaad3eef20f553ffe1191e2fa0e7946da274968f3811d2cb21b50e73002c
manager1:     - SHA1:f529a30f513ac3f896ad9d0f63a6e6e050095071 [weak]
manager1:     - MD5Sum:43891c37db034c6a084ea04abb463f5a [weak]
manager1:     - Filesize:28140650 [weak]
manager1:    Last modification reported: Thu, 08 Sep 2022 20:43:28 +0000
manager1: E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
manager1:    Hashes of expected file:
manager1:     - SHA512:be66b6bef0f9a64ba6669b2360882db0f5ed5f5d32f6a4bf0421b49e7dd7432cedd44e26d74dffa13f30ec3f70d4db96350f8411c6ee2523f7195848e7baeac2
manager1:     - SHA256:995152b8e8ad73cff59ad2756c82ea40ab5634b862bcca1037ee945a811b99cf
manager1:     - SHA1:be8ffe23e1f5ac53b559784376cea29e748a2998 [weak]
manager1:     - MD5Sum:b0431ee9f86ad0d415d153a6ece57145 [weak]
manager1:     - Filesize:41490986 [weak]
manager1:    Hashes of received file:
manager1:     - SHA512:1ecbac81e9eb947fe04fe9f61614af476e1a4893c4a31283af7e4c8ba89afe45bf27598a6cf36703cbd43cfe774748ec09b23baf0f78eebb6f9f70e4e42c82f7
manager1:     - SHA256:037606a8f7a734f743759d1d5c36f3e81c1bd7e7409d38e5322cddf3a20f9621
manager1:     - SHA1:be8ffe23e1f5ac53b559784376cea29e748a2998 [weak]
manager1:     - MD5Sum:b0431ee9f86ad0d415d153a6ece57145 [weak]
manager1:     - Filesize:41490986 [weak]
manager1:    Last modification reported: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 09:01:03 +0000
manager1: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
manager1: Failed to restart docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

And I have modified the Vagrantfile to something like this below

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

# vi: set ft=ruby :

boxes = [
    {
        :name => "manager1",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.10",
        :mem => "512",
        :cpu => "1"
    },
    {
        :name => "manager2",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.11",
        :mem => "512",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "manager3",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.12",
        :mem => "512",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "worker1",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.13",
        :mem => "1024",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "worker2",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.14",
        :mem => "1024",
        :cpu => "2"
    },
    {
        :name => "worker3",
        :eth1 => "192.168.205.15",
         :mem => "1024",
         :cpu => "2"
    }
 ]

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"

  config.vm.boot_timeout = 2000

  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v, override|
      override.vm.box = "base"
  end

  # Turn off shared folders
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: true

  boxes.each do |opts|
    config.vm.define opts[:name] do |config|
      config.vm.hostname = opts[:name]

      config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
        v.vmx["memsize"] = opts[:mem]
        v.vmx["numvcpus"] = opts[:cpu]
      end

      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", opts[:name]]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", opts[:mem]]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", opts[:cpu]]
      end

      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: opts[:eth1]
    end

   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get clean
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y upgrade
    apt-get -y install \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg-agent \
        software-properties-common
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
    apt-get clean
    apt-get update
    curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-scan-plugin_0.17.0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-rootless-extras_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.6.8-1_amd64.deb
    curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    sudo apt install ./docker-scan-plugin_0.17.0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    sudo apt install ./docker-ce-rootless-extras_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    sudo apt install ./containerd.io_1.6.8-1_amd64.deb
    sudo apt install ./docker-ce-cli_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
    sudo apt install ./docker-ce_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
        getent group docker || groupadd docker
        usermod -aG docker vagrant
        service docker restart
    SHELL
  end
end
```

Yet I am still having errors such as this in different positions of the installation progress display messages

```
manager1: Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-scan-plugin amd64 0.17.0~ubuntu-focal [3521 kB]
manager1: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
manager1: Unpacking docker-scan-plugin (0.17.0~ubuntu-focal) ...
manager1: Setting up docker-scan-plugin (0.17.0~ubuntu-focal) ...
manager1: WARNING: 
manager1: apt
manager1:  
manager1: does not have a stable CLI interface. 
manager1: Use with caution in scripts.
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
manager1:    - Filesize:8392456 [weak]
manager1:   Last modification reported: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 09:01:04 +0000
manager1: Fetched 8392 kB in 14s (592 kB/s)
manager1: E
manager1: : 
manager1: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-rootless-extras_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
manager1:    
manager1: Hashes of expected file:
manager1:     - SHA512:a157e61be464612c83b5739792beec6bbf4ecffe581d26be30c1abbdf78f325569abea87ad2d7a1ed1ec0a7df3dd1c5209b6998368730d4de03b1ba9429dffa0
manager1:     - SHA256:e7e3f7d874ef3b6a81a2bb453b013a8b902f44020cf98fb903f79643125da0e2
manager1:     - SHA1:b6baad11031fbb46f452b26acd50b919409f66da [weak]
manager1:     - MD5Sum:9e4d78d39526a215879bea52b869c65c [weak]
manager1:     - Filesize:8392456 [weak]
manager1:    Hashes of received file:
manager1:     - SHA512:a157e61be464612c83b5739792beec6bbf4ecffe581d26be30c1abbdf78f325569abea87ad2d7a1ed1ec0a7df3dd1c5209b6998368730d4de03b1ba9429dffa0
manager1:     - SHA256:abcaa85388bc4f8416101cf4141c1f5f262798206f12ac66501a4f75c16a7d6b
manager1:     - SHA1:b6baad11031fbb46f452b26acd50b919409f66da [weak]
manager1:     - MD5Sum:9e4d78d39526a215879bea52b869c65c [weak]
manager1:     - Filesize:8392456 [weak]
manager1:    Last modification reported: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 09:01:04 +0000
manager1: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
manager1: WARNING: 
manager1: apt
manager1:  
manager1: does not have a stable CLI interface. 
manager1: Use with caution in scripts.
manager1: Reading package lists...
manager1: E
manager1: : 
manager1: Invalid archive member header
manager1: E
manager1: : 
manager1: Could not read meta data from /home/vagrant/containerd.io_1.6.8-1_amd64.deb
manager1: E
manager1: : The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
manager1: WARNING: 
manager1: apt
manager1:  
manager1: does not have a stable CLI interface. 
manager1: Use with caution in scripts.

......................................................
.....................................................
....................................................
manager1:    - SHA1:ad6d369560655b309a9108bc218e49ae54dfa90c [weak]
manager1:    - MD5Sum:b0431ee9f86ad0d415d153a6ece57145 [weak]
manager1:    - Filesize:41490986 [weak]
manager1:   Last modification reported: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 09:01:03 +0000
manager1: Fetched 41.5 MB in 56s (742 kB/s)
manager1: E
manager1: : 
manager1: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
manager1:    
manager1: Hashes of expected file:
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA512:be66b6bef0f9a64ba6669b2360882db0f5ed5f5d32f6a4bf0421b49e7dd7432cedd44e26d74dffa13f30ec3f70d4db96350f8411c6ee2523f7195848e7baeac2
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA256:995152b8e8ad73cff59ad2756c82ea40ab5634b862bcca1037ee945a811b99cf
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA1:be8ffe23e1f5ac53b559784376cea29e748a2998 [weak]
manager1:    
manager1:  - MD5Sum:b0431ee9f86ad0d415d153a6ece57145 [weak]
manager1:    
manager1:  - Filesize:41490986 [weak]
manager1:    
manager1: Hashes of received file:
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA512:d1c450b1bc78c44e2da788129b3bf4812811b40c176fe7069f7ec2928d29aee8027a758266e360e1c232846902379b7516cb8dde6ce721d2f07b15e642461f84
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA256:be60933dfbca1778c175423cad6efcf018532ec515705fef105c1c0ee7b2c3da
manager1:    
manager1:  - SHA1:ad6d369560655b309a9108bc218e49ae54dfa90c [weak]
manager1:    
manager1:  - MD5Sum:b0431ee9f86ad0d415d153a6ece57145 [weak]
manager1:    
manager1:  - Filesize:41490986 [weak]
manager1:    
manager1: Last modification reported: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 09:01:03 +0000
manager1: E
manager1: : 
manager1: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
manager1: WARNING: 
manager1: apt
manager1:  
manager1: does not have a stable CLI interface. 
manager1: Use with caution in scripts.

...............................
..............................

manager1: Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
manager1: Failed to restart docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Please I need help to enable me create vms and install docker.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your provisioning script:

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

before any apt-get calls.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/500764/dpkg-reconfigure-unable-to-re-open-stdin-no-file-or-directory?newreg=ab3bcf217d7e4a42bbbd82c3ce852392